# DHCP forwarding in FreshTomato

Tags: router, dhcp, dd-wrt, tomato

I have a wireless router that has a DHCP server (let's call it R1) and I connected another wireless router [linksys E2500 V3] (let's call it R2) to it using a LAN cable. R2 has a FreshTomato installed and I am trying to turn off the DHCP server so instead, it would just forward the DHCP from R1 to clients connected to it. In DD-WRT firmware there is an explicit option to forward DHCP so I am wondering can this be accomplished in FreshTomato?

The IP address of the R1 is 192.168.1.1. In DD-WRT we would set the IP address of R2 to 192.168.2.1 so it wouldn't conflict with R1 and then set the DHCP server to 192.168.1.1 and that's it.

This is the setup on R2.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a checkbox for DHCP on the Basic -> Network page under the LAN section.
[image]
If you want to use the WAN port you also need to bridge the WAN port to the LAN ports, following the Bridge WAN ? link on this page will take you to the VLAN page where you can uncheck the WAN port on the WAN0 bridge and then check it on the LAN0 bridge.
[image]

Comment: I did that and it worked. I now have an IP assigned to me by R1. But now I don't know what is the IP of the R2? when I log in to R1 I don't see R2 has been assigned any IP. So I don't know how to log in to R2

Comment: It will be the IP Address entered on the Basic -> Network page (in my screen shot it is 192.168.1.2). If you are using Fresh Tomato on your primary router you can select arping under Network Discovery mode on the devices list page and it should be able to detect the router.

Comment: oops. I didn't see that.